# how to hide and show the elements in tableviewcell based on cell selection

Tags: ios, swift4.2

I have been trying to hide and show UIView which is in tableviewcell based on cell selection.when the cell is selected, then the view should be visible and if the cell index is changed then the view should be invisible in the last selected cell and should be visible in current selected cell.If any one helps me would be great,Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can directly put the code in cellForRowAt method.  cell.view.isHidden = !cell.isSelected

Comment: If you want update cell height after hide element in stackView, you should connect delegate and call tableView

tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the UITableView Delegate method

`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

And in this method store the selected row in a variable and reloads your tableview.
Then in

`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

show/hide the view for the row based on the selected row variable.

Answer (score 0):

Put the Views in Tableviewcell inside a stackView & then on cell selection in didselectRow you can simply hide or unhide views.